# Rotate square matrix clockwise by 90degrees

Tags: c, matrix, memory-management

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<malloc.h>

void nl(void) {     //function to print new line
    printf("\n");
}

int** allocate(_size) {
    int** matrix=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*_size);
    for(int i=0;i<_size;i++) {
        matrix[i]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*_size);
    }
    return matrix;
}

void scanMatrix(_matrix,_size)
int** _matrix;
{
    printf("Enter the values: ");
    for(int i=0;i<_size;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<_size;j++) {
            scanf("%d",&_matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void printMatrix(_matrix,_size)
int** _matrix;
{
    for(int i=0;i<_size;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<_size;j++) {
            printf("%d ",_matrix[i][j]);
        }
        nl();
    }
}

void swap(num1,num2)
int* num1;
int* num2;
{
    *num1=*num1+*num2;
    *num2=*num1-*num2;
    *num1=*num1-*num2;
}

void rotateMatrix(_matrix,_size)
int** _matrix;
{
    for(int i=0;i<_size;i++) {
        for(int j=i+1;j<_size;j++) {
            swap(&_matrix[i][j],&_matrix[j][i]);
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<_size;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<_size/2;j++) {
            swap(&_matrix[i][j],&_matrix[i][_size-1-j]);
        }
    }
}

main(argc,argv)
const char** argv;
{
    int size=0;
    printf("Enter the size of the square matrix: ");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    int** matrix=allocate(size);
    scanMatrix(matrix,size);
    printMatrix(matrix,size);
    nl();
    rotateMatrix(matrix,size);
    nl();
    printMatrix(matrix,size);
    return 0;
}
```

This code doesn't use extra memory and also uses run-time allocation using `malloc`. However, has a time complexity of O(n^2). How do I further optimise it?

Comment: How did you come up with O(n^2)? I'd say it Is O(size^2)=O(n). Anyway why is `swap()` so complicated?

Comment: Even Swap doesn't use extra memory. Regarding n, why do you say that n=size^2? Will you please elaborate? :)

Comment: Btw how do you call the syntax with function argument types defined after the function prototypes? I have never seen this syntax. How do I refer to it?

Comment: Just search for Kernighan and Ritchie notation on Google. :) It isn't standard syntax and was used by Ritchie. I use it because I learnt C from first edition of `The C programming language`. Don't use it if possible :)

Comment: Well I suppose n Is the number of elements in the matrix. Since the matrix Is square i Believe number of elements Is size^2 where size Is the size of edge of the square Matrix.

Comment: However, it does keep your function signature compact. And, I find it easy to read:
The first line shows the variable names.
From second line it shows type. Also, from what I heard (I am not sure about this), the compiler finds it easy to parse this syntax, especially, if it is passing its output to a 2 pass assembler. .... To all of you reading this, is it true?

Comment: @slepic anytime you say \$\mathcal O(n)\$, you must define what you mean by \$n\$. Otherwise it’s not reliable.

Comment: @slepic This is C using the Original K&R C. I was surprised that it still compiled I spent 2 years converting this kind of code to the ANSI standard in the 1990s.

Comment: Awesome grit. BTW, is it true that this syntax works more efficient in 2 pass assembler?

Comment: @RollandIllig Which I did. Whats your point? Anyway. No. Not Always. In a formal document maybe. In an informal discussion where it Is obvious from context? Not necesary... You also dont Always define what you mean by "+". Only if you mean something non standard. It Is pretty Common that n in O(n) Stands for number of elements. And from the context it Is obvious that this Is the case. And btw if you wanted to object So much, why not object to OP? He didnt specify what n Is in the first place. Nevertheless we all somehow understood what He means....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

regarding:

```
void rotateMatrix(_matrix,_size)
```

1. do NOT use leading underscores for variable and/or parameter names.
2. a function signature must have the variable types as part of the signature.
3. when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings

regarding:

```
main(argc,argv)
```

there are two valid signatures for the `main()` function, the are:

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
int main( void )
```

the posted signature is missing the return type and the parameters are missing the needed typing

regarding:

```
main(argc,argv)
const char** argv;
```

1. This is an obsolete method of writing a function signature, that was replaced back in the late '80s.
2. some 20+ years ago, the 'default' of a untyped variable and/or function parameter defaulting to `int` was discarded.

regarding:

```
void nl(void) {     //function to print new line
printf("\n");
}
```

this function should be deleted.  Then when wanting to print a newline, use:

```
puts( "" );
```

regarding this kind of statement:

```
int** matrix=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*_size);
```

1. in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code.
2. when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc()` `calloc()` and/or `realloc()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, then call `perror( "malloc failed" );` to inform the user of the problem.

Regarding:

```
scanf("%d",&size);
```

when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  Those functions return the number of successful 'input format conversion specifiers'.  In the current statement suggest:

```
if( scanf("%d",&size) != 1 )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "scanf for size failed\n" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

for readability and ease of understanding: Please insert a reasonable space:

1. inside parens
2. inside braces
3. inside brackets
4. after commas
5. after semicolons
6. around C operators

regarding the function: `scanMatrix()`

1. The posted code fails to keep the user informed of where in the matrix the next number entered will be placed nor when all the numbers have been entered.

Suggest the calls to `nl()` in `main()` be moved to the end of the functions: `rotateMatrix()` and `printMatrix()`

the posted code has several memory leaks as it fails to pass the pointers to each of the allocated memory areas to `free()`

Comment: Note: "there are two valid signatures for the main() function," --> true, yet an implementation can have others. "or in some other implementation-defined manner." § 5.1.2.2.1 1

Comment: Minor: Using `printf("\n")`, `puts( "" )` or `putchar( '\n' )` will emit the same efficient code with a good compiler. Best to code for clarity than concern about an only potential small linear optimization.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica,  Only emits the same efficient code if optimization turned up.

Answer (score 5):

> has a time complexity of O(n^2).

I think you are incorrectly using "n" as if it is the size of the n×n matrix.

The "n" in O() notation refers to the total size of the input data.

So, for a m×m matrix, the "n" value for complexity would be m<sup>2</sup>.

Your algorithm is O(n).

---

> This code doesn't use extra memory

Is there a specific reason for doing the swap trick the way you did rather than simply using the more obvious method with an `auto int temp;` on the stack?

`auto` memory is allocated on a stack, so it exists only during the invocation of the function.
After that, it can be reused by other functions.
Unless a function is called recursively, there's no cumulative problem with using temporary stack space; that's what it's for.

And if an algorithm should ever actually require persistent storage, it would be done using `static` rather than `auto`.

---

> This is C using the Original K&R C.

The biggest drawback to using that is that you don't get the benefit of typechecking, which was introduced in C89.

The compiler won't notice any problem with this:

```
swap(&_matrix[i][j],&_matrix[j][i]);
swap(_matrix[i][j],_matrix[j][i]);
swap("me", "you");
```

but at runtime things will fail.

I hope you are at least using `lint` on the source to check for such problems.

Comment: You answered your own question . I wanted to use as less memory as possible.

Comment: @RayButterworth could your comment be part of your review?  if so, please edit it into your answer appropriately with enough context to explain how it pertains to code in question.  Comments are not meant to be used for additional review and could be deleted at any time.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 The suggested swap here does not use more more memory than the posted code (`printMatrix()` easily runs much deeper on the stack)  so the question remains as to why use this problematic swap.  Perhaps one could ask, why think the original code saves memory?

Comment: Ray, Given `scanf("%d",&size);`, algorithm is O(size*size).  I agree the prompt `printf("Enter the size of the square matrix: ");` does leave room for confusion.

Comment: Hmmm "This is C using the Original K&R C." and apparently newer features too with `for(int i=0;i<_size;i++)` vs. `int i;  ... for(i=0;i<_size;i++)`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica says "*algorithm is O(size*size)*".  Correct.  The size of the input is also "size*size", not simply "size".  The "n" in O(n) notation would be the same as n=size*size.  But the original question used "n" as if it represented "size" rather than "size*size".  If one triples the "size", nine times as much processing is needed, but the size of the input matrix will also be nine times larger, so the effect is linear, hence it is an O(n) algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

As memory management is one of the question's tags, writing swap that way is **NOT** the way to go:

- Harder to understand
- Risks overflows
- Is less efficient when looking at the compilation result: https://godbolt.org/z/iBlZ8n

The first thing to change if memory management is a concern is the allocation of the matrix. Allocate it as a continuous chunk of memory, without extra pointers.

Comment: UV for the good memory squeezing idea.   Even remaining with the extra level `int **`, the allocation of pointers and `int`s could be done in one step, saving the allocation overhead.  Its somewhat ugly code to do that, but does save real memory over OP's `_size + 1` allocations